# Mesh based warping v/s splatting based warping for view synthesis

Tags: graphics, computer-vision

Among image warping methods for novel view synthesis problem, (i.e. given the RGB-D image for view1, computing the image for view2), there are two broad methods - mesh based warping and splat based warping. Has it been shown that one is better than the other? If not, what are the drawbacks/limitations of mesh based and splat based warping methods?